# rsync command works on Linux, not Mac OS X

Tags: linux, mac-osx, rsync, mac, operating-system

I recently migrated from Linux to Mac for my primary machine. I use rsync to update several static websites. Here's the command:

```
rsync -avzu —exclude=.git /Users/[me]/src/[site] [user]@[host]:/home/public
```

The command ignores the git folder and uploads other local changes to the website. The command works on Linux, but not on Mac.

On Mac, rsync registers which files need to be uploaded, but the changes aren't made on the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Timestamps are likely off between the systems and `-u` is causing it to skip some files because they look newer on the destination.

Comment: Can you also add `-v` for verbosity?

Comment: OSX does not use GNU tools, which sometimes gives a different set of parameters.

Comment: @casperghst42: `rsync` is the same on all platforms, because there is only one implementation (what you say is correct for tools like `find` etc. which indeed have differences between the GNU and BSD implementations).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like slashes matter, this works: `rsync -avzu --exclude=.git /Users/[me]/src/[site]/ [user]@[host]:/home/public`